# Backtest over specific dates in Quanstrat R

Tags: r, quantstrat

How do I backtest over specific dates, for example 2008::2010 in Quanstrat? 
I want to load symbols from 2001::2017, but i only want to back test over a subset of dates. (rather than reload the symbols every time for specific date ranges)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this in `quantstrat`.  In fact, there is a comment at the beginning of the *apply** functions that says:

```
#TODO add Date subsetting
```

(patches welcome)

There are a number of possible ways to do this with the existing code though.

Probably the simplest way is to load all your market data into an environment, and then subset your market data into the .GlobalEnv before each call to `applyStrategy`.

Indicators and signals should use vectorized functions, and should take (at most) seconds to apply to the entire series.  So the simplest thing is probably to run `applyIndicators` and `applySignals` manually over the entire series, and then call `applyRules` with just the subset you want.

You could also add a signal function that does understand subsets.  This signal function would be last in the strategy specification, and would filter all your other signals to 0 outside of your preferred date range.

Comment: The current version of the code as of this comment adds a rule_subset argument to applyRules which will apply rules only to the subset period.